# Apple LLVM 8.0 optimizations flags

Tags: c++, optimization, llvm, compiler-flags

Apple LLVM similar to GCC has some major optimization flags: O1, O2, O3 etc. For GCC I can watch exactly command-line flags [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) and some of them are the same for LLVM.

How to know all the flags for LLVM?

Comment: The [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) C and C++ frontend is [CLang](http://clang.llvm.org/) which has a [user manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, saw that - no information about optimization options. And besides, I'm expecting that someone know kind of console command which shows that options for exactly version of LLVM.

Comment: `clang -help` provides a list of all switches.